# Rails validates_uniqueness_of :scope on foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, validates-uniqueness-of

I have a model "Product" that belongs_to "Store" (which has_many "products").
I want to validate the uniqueness of the product name but only within each store.

Right now I have this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :store_id
end
```

When I run a save on any product now I get:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: column name is not unique
```

I'm sure there is a simple error I'm making here.  Please educate me.

Thanks,

Harris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that error is coming from SQLite, not Rails. Check the constraints at the database level - maybe you added a unique constraint on :name rather than [:name, :store_id].

Comment: Thanks Brian, the constraints were the issue.